# ISO-8859 and NodeJS JSON.Stringify

Tags: json, node.js, localization, iso-8859-1

I am converting translation files to JSON in NodeJS.

I have strings like:

```
Cadrer sur la sélection
Navigateur dépassé détecté !
```

and I am trying to convert them to UTF-8 so I can json.stringify them.

However, I end up with string that look like:

```
Navigateur d�pass� d�tect� !
```

Below is a shorten example of my code ...

```
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < messages.length;i++){
    var iconv = new Iconv("ISO-8859-1", 'UTF-8');
    var buffer = iconv.convert(messages[i]); // the ISO-8859-1 str
    obj[i] = buffer.toString();
}
var jsonLocale = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language is this code in?  What frameworks and application environment are you using?